# Is it possible to write on a mounted hard-drive that has Apple HFS/HFS+ file system

Tags: mount, external-hdd, readonly, tails-os

Running the latest Tails I have attached my hard-drive that got automatically mounted. However it seems  only to be read-only.

Is there a way to mount it in read/write ? Or is this not possible since the file system is Apple HFS/HFS+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo umount mount_point
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw drive mount_point
```

you need to use force if you want to mount it as rw otherwise it fall back to ro

Comment: Is it read-only by default because it is still experimental code, or am I missing something?

Comment: It worked for me but with "hfsplus", without the "d"